# minimax complexity tic tac toe

Tags: time-complexity

minimax complexity has an upper bound complexity *of o(b^m)*, where b are the legal moves in the game and m the depth of the search tree.

For an unbounded tic-tac-toe search, the max depth would be 9, and the number of legal moves goes decreasing as the search deepens e.g.  at depth 0 it's 9, at depth 1 8 and so on. Thus the complexity should be *o(m!)*.

However my current implementation gives *434746* iterations to the minimax function (for the first movement), which leads me to think that my previous analysis is wrong.   Any hints/ideas?

*9^9 > 434746 > 9!*

Update: as it turns out the complexity relation can be expressed as

```
T n = n + n* T(n-1)
T 1 = 1
```

At the start we have n branches but each of these branches has n-1 branches.  For example when we have only 3 moves left the upper bound is 15 (my implementation yields 11).  At the start we have 9 moves the upperbound is 986409 significantly smaller than 9^9.

Is there any way to express this better?

Comment: The total number of states tends not to have an exact expression, exactly because not all moves are allowed at each step. The best you can do is upper-bound it roughly, or empirically estimate it.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus thanks for your note. I don't want the exact the number but a better upper bound better than m^b hence the recurrence relation T n = n + n* T(n-1)

Comment: Your recurrence relation has the solution $T(n) = (n+1)!/2$.